# XmlSerializer and Collection property with private setter

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

Say I have a simple class like so

```
[Serializeable]
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
       this.MyCollection = new List<int>();
    }


    public List<int> MyCollection { get; private set;}
}
```

If I try to deserialize this using XmlSerializer I get an error saying that MyCollection is readonly and cannot be assigned to. However I don't want to make the setter public as this can cause all kinds of problems if the user of the class assigns to it. FxCop rightly warns against this: [Collection properties should be read only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327(VS.80).aspx)

However on the bottom of the page in the community added content is this:

> XmlSerializer understands read-only
>   collections                    Collection
>   properties do not have to be
>   read-write for the XmlSerializer to
>   serialize and deserialize the contents
>   correctly. The XmlSerializer will look
>   for a method called Add on collection
>   properties that implement ICollection
>   or IEnumerable, and use that to
>   populate the collection when
>   deserializing an instance of the owner
>   type.

However it just doesn't seem to be the case (as I get the InvalidOperationException). What am I able to do that obeys the best practice of keeping the property setter private while still allowing me to use the XmlSerializer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your private setter is causing the issue. The XmlSerializer class will work fine with the class I have given below. The XmlSerializer class was invented before private setters were introduced, so it is probably not checking that correctly when it scans the class type using reflection. Maybe you should report this to Microsoft as a bug.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<int> _myCollection;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _myCollection = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> MyCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return this._myCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This bug (feature?) still present in .NET 4 :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [XmlIgnore] Attribute